# How to implement thousand separator in string Data Frame without modifications in one row with percentage values in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have Pandas Data Frame in Python like below, be aware that every value is STRING!:

```
IDX | COL1 | COL2
------------------
ABC | 130  | 0
DEF | 5409 | 346
GHI | 34.9 | 25.3
```

And i try to implement here thousand separator in above Data Frame, so I need something like below:

```
IDX | COL1 | COL2
------------------
ABC | 130   | 0
DEF | 5 409 | 346
GHI | 34.9  | 25.3
```

BE AWARE:

1. each value is string
2. IDX column is index
3. index GHI has only percent values like: 34.9 and 25.3 and this rows should stay WITHOUT any modifications

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this function onto `.apply()`

```py
def thousand_sep(text):
    try:
        text = int(text)
        return "{:,}".format(text)
    except:
        return str(text)

print(thousand_sep("1918.18"))
```

For practical use-case:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def thousand_sep(text):
    try:
        text = int(text)
        return "{:,}".format(text)
    except:
        return str(text)


df = pd.DataFrame(data={"COL1":{"ABC":"130", "DEF":"5409", "GHI":"34.9"}, "COL2":{"ABC":"0", "DEF":"346", "GHI":"25.3"}})
df["COL1"], df["COL2"] = np.vectorize(thousand_sep) ([df['COL1'], df['COL2']])
print(df)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a work-around to get a " " instead of a "," after the 3 digits.

Comment: could you show me how to implement this function on my Data Frame "df" ?

Comment: Because this function work for one text for example 12344, but I need to implement it on Data Frame

Comment: Ok, so please show mi how to implement it on Data Frame not only one value, please :)

Comment: Check the edit out and see if it fits your requirements! (and don't worry about `np.vectorize()` its just a faster way of using `df.apply()`)

Comment: @Matop I have done some big fixes check it out

Comment: Is it possible to implement it on for example selected 10 columns or I have to implement this function separately for each column ?

Comment: @Matop I've never done that personally, but I might try to do it

Comment: Could be great, because everything is ok and I gave you best answer but it will be perfect to be able to implement it on a few columns :)

Comment: Hmm, great, but as I assume, you do not know how to change "," to " " ?

Comment: I made it: df= d.refplace(",", " ", regex = True) it works :)